# Find first specified char that is not quotes

Tags: php, regex

I am tryin to figure out how to find first occurence of specified character (lets say =) in string. This is easy, but i want position of that = only if its NOT in quotes.

For example, in this case:

```
  foo = bar
```

I want position of first =, but in this case:

```
  "foo = bar" = baz
```

I want position of the second =.

I found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721921/how-could-i-find-all-whitespaces-excluding-the-ones-between-quotes) here, but I need position, not splitting. And I must be able to deal with escaped quotes \" or \' so I think I wont be able to use string based approach to this problem.

One of my ideas was using lex. analysis with regexp based syntax analysis, which can find first occurence of = for me, but it seems rather heavy :)

Comment: What is your goal/orignal task? Maybe there is an easier solution…

Comment: I don't think you can do it with just regex alone.

Comment: your not looking for the last pos of =? in that case use strrpos

Comment: I think you will have to write a lexer. It's a colossal work...

Comment: Grumpy: I am not looking for the last = because string may look like this:
"foo = bar" = "baz = john doe"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be possible with a regular expression because quotes cannot be nested, something like the following:

```
^([^="]|"(\\"|[^"])*")*(=)
```

You'll need to find the index position of the final matched group `(=)`.

Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/jt5CSIaOjo

Comment: the position can be found in php like this:
`preg_match('/^([^="]|"(\\"|[^"])*")*(=)/',$searchstring,$matches,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);`