# PHP ignore whitespace inside string to form an array

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am having a string in PHP like this-

```
$str = "Foo var1='Abook' var2='A book'";
```

I am trying to convert this string to array that will treat the words inside the `''` quotes as single statement (i.e they will ignore the spaces inside `''` quotes).
So my array will look like

```
Array
(
   [0] => "Foo",
   [1] => "var1='Abook'",
   [3] => "var2='A book'"
)
```

Note that the array is formed the seperating the string by the space **outside** `''` quotes, But not inside it.

Can you please give me some good preg function so that I can accomplish this.

Comment: Have you checked this out? http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: I have already tried explode, but it doesnot skips the whitespaces inside the quotes `''`. I am trying to implement `preg_match_all`

Comment: @TJFogarty exploding by space will separate 'A book', creating `var2='A` and `book'`

Comment: I'm an idiot. Apologies :p

Comment: This may help you.  Please note that it does both double and single quote: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721921/how-could-i-find-all-whitespaces-excluding-the-ones-between-quotes

Comment: thanks, worked like charm. That made my day

Answer (score 1):

This will work for your sample input and output, but may not be general purpose enough for you.  It's at least a starting point:

```
<?php
  $str = "Foo var1='Abook' var2='A book'";
  $res = array();

  $bits = explode(' ', $str, 2);

  $res[] = $bits[0];

  if (preg_match_all("/\w+='[^']+'/", $bits[1], $matches) !== false) {
    $res = array_merge($res, $matches[0]);
  }

  print_r($res);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem-

```
$str= 'word1 word2 \'this is a phrase\' word3 word4 "this is a second phrase" word5 word1 word2 "this is a phrase" word3 word4 "this is a second phrase" word5';

$regexp = '/\G(?:"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\'|[^"\'\s]+)*\K\s+/';

$arr = preg_split($regexp, $str);

print_r($arr);
```

Original link [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721921/how-could-i-find-all-whitespaces-excluding-the-ones-between-quotes).
Obviously I needed only the correct regexp. Problem solved!!!

Answer (score 0):

here what you need:

`$array = explode(' ', $str);`

**UPDATE**

You can try this:

```
preg_match_all('/\'([^\']+)\'/', $string, $matches);
$matches = $matches[1];
```

Get all text between  `' '` replace spaces to `{SPACE}`
so your string would look like `$str = "var1='A{SPACE}book'"` then you can do `explode()` by spaces.

mmm?

Comment: That will kick 'A book' into two too

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = "Foo var1='Abook' var2='A book'";
preg_match_all("~(?:(?<=^| )[^']+(?= |$)|(?<=^| )[^']+'[^']+'(?= |$))~", $s, $m);
print_r($m[0]);

Outputs:
Array
(
  [0] => Foo
  [1] => var1='Abook'
  [2] => var2='A book'
)
```