# Best way to split a string by word (SQL Batch separator)

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a class I use to "split" a string of SQL commands by a batch separator - e.g. "GO" - into a list of SQL commands that are run in turn etc.

```
...
private static IEnumerable<string> SplitByBatchIndecator(string script, string batchIndicator)
{
    string pattern = string.Concat("^\\s*", batchIndicator, "\\s*$");
    RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline;
    foreach (string batch in Regex.Split(script, pattern, options))
    {
        yield return batch.Trim();
    }
}
```

My current implementation uses a `Regex` with `yield` but I am not sure if it's the "best" way.

- It should be quick
- It should handle large strings (I have some scripts that are 10mb in size for example)
- **The hardest part (that the above code currently does not do) is to take quoted text into account**

Currently the following SQL will incorrectly get split:

```
var batch = QueryBatch.Parse(@"-- issue...
insert into table (name, desc)
values('foo', 'if the
go
is on a line by itself we have a problem...')");

Assert.That(batch.Queries.Count, Is.EqualTo(1), "This fails for now...");
```

I have thought about a token based parser that tracks the state of the open closed quotes but am not sure if Regex will do it.

Any ideas!?

Comment: Now that is an evil problem, which is also giving me a headache. I'm working on https://github.com/timabell/sqlHawk which also needs to support batches. I'm half inclined to just say tough and that all the scripts must be split by GO on a line on it's own in uppercase and all variants will be ignored. Otherwise I'm down to full SQL parsing :-/

Comment: GO reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx

Comment: An alternative approach for .net people: use a different method of running the script: https://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/05/12/c-executing-batch-t-sql-scripts-with-go-statements/ "2. Use the Server class from SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)"

Comment: @Tim Abell - "tough" has been my approach to date! No batch counter or comments... Would probably get away with a partial token parser, quotes and comments for example but its not been a big enough issue for me yet :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can track the opening and closing quotes using a [Balancing Group Definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#balancing_group_definition).

Also, a similar question was asked last year about [splitting on whitespace as long as the whitespace wasn't contained in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554013/regular-expression-to-split-on-spaces-unless-in-quotes). You might be able to adjust those answers to get where you're going.

Comment: The 'balancing group definition' was close but not quite what I needed - the problem was you need pairs of quotes so it doesn't fit well with a commented out single quote in the SQL for example. Nice method none the less!