# How can I support the SQL GO statement in a Java / jtds application?

Tags: java, sql-server, t-sql, jtds

I'm working on a Java based OSS app [SqlHawk](http://timabell.github.com/sqlHawk/) which as one of its features is to run upgrade sql scripts against a server.

Microsoft have made it a convention to split a script into batches with the [GO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx) statement, which is a good idea but just asking for false matches on the string.

At the moment I have a very rudimentary:

```
// split where GO on its own on a line
Pattern batchSplitter = Pattern.compile("^GO", Pattern.MULTILINE);
...
String[] splitSql = batchSplitter.split(definition);
...
```

which kind of works but is prone to being tripped up by things like [quoted GO statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619485/best-way-to-split-a-string-by-word-sql-batch-separator) or indentation issues.

I think the only way to make this truly reliable is to have an SQL parser in the app, but I have no idea how to go about this, or whether that might actually end up being less reliable (especially given this tool supports multiple DBMSs).

What ways could I solve this problem? Code examples would be very helpful to me here.

*[Relevant sqlHawk code](https://github.com/timabell/sqlHawk/blob/8984514737c4720ab398c817fd3faeafdbef03d1/src/uk/co/timwise/sqlhawk/db/write/DbWriter.java#L215) on github.*

Currently using [jtds](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) to execute the batches found in the scripts.

Comment: I did it your way when I had to do a similar thing. It's only used internally and works fine for us.

Comment: Idem here... It's far from fool-proof and you need to decide if you want to support things like 'GO 100'. The main hurdle IMHO is when the GO is part of a /* comment block */. Those require quite a bit of extra processing. (strip out all comments & comment block first, then do the split is what we did)
PS: You can prefix the code with `SET PARSEONLY ON` and if there is no 'Incorrect syntax near GO' there is no need to split the code.. otherwise you might use the line-location indicated by the error to 'pinpoint where to split on a `GO`... might work, feels more complex than needed though...

Comment: example to complicate things : `EXEC (' SET PARSEONLY ON;SELECT * FROM t_entity; GO; PRINT 0')`

Comment: Could your project export the ddl modifications in an XML format then process the statements separately?  http://db.apache.org/ddlutils/documentation.html does something like this.

Comment: Gave up, left an open issue https://github.com/timabell/sqlHawk/issues/49 & went for requiring GO to be on its own on a line.

Comment: @TimAbell - did you look at the code I posted? I wouldn't have thought it would be so hard to convert C# to Java.

Comment: I did but I haven't had time to go through it in more detail. It looks good and I've voted up your answer.

Answer (score 1):

GO is a client batch seperator command. You can replace it with ;. It should not be sent in your EXEC dynamic SQL.

```
USE master
GO --<----- client actually send the first batch to SQL and wait for a response
SELECT * from sys.databases
GO
```

Should be translated in

```
Application.Exec("USE master");
Application.Exec("SELECT * from sys.databases");
```

or you can write it this way:

```
Application.Exec("'USE master;SELECT * from sys.databases")
```

More about GO
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037(v=sql.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't give me any clues how I might reliably perform the split in Java. I think you are right about EXEC but I haven't checked.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this isn't going to be *exactly* what you want, but you might find it a start. I released SchemaEngine (which forms the core of most of my products) as open source [here](http://www.atlantis-interactive.co.uk/blog/post/2011/02/24/Free-SQL-Server-Schema-Synchronisation-Engine-announcing-the-release-of-the-AtlantisSchemaEngine-source-code.aspx). In there, you will find C# code that does what you want very reliably (i.e. not tripping up with strings, comments etc etc). It also support the 'GO x' syntax to repeat a batch x times.

If you download that and have a look in `/Atlantis.SchemaEngine/Helpers` you'll find a class called `BatchParser.cs` which contains a method called `ParseBatches` - which does pretty much what it says on the tin.