# C# - Regular Expression to split string on spaces, unless a double quote is encountered

Tags: c#, regex

This thread is very similar to what I want: [Regular Expression to split on spaces unless in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554013/regular-expression-to-split-on-spaces-unless-in-quotes)

But I need a few extra rules that I cannot figure out:
- the above thread does split on spaces, unless they're in double quotes. However, it splits on punctuation as well.  I need Anything inside the double quotes to remain as one entity.

For example:
**/Update setting0 value="new value" /Save**  should return
/Update
setting0
value=
new value *(I don't care whether it trims the quotes off or not)*
/Save

**/Import "C:\path\file.xml" "C:\path_2\file_2.xml" /Exit** should return
/Import
C:\path\file.xml *(I don't care whether it trims the quotes off or not)*
C:\path_2\file_2.xml
/Exit

I ended up using this expression from the thread above:

```
(?<=")\w[\w\s]*(?=")|\w+|"[\w\s]*"
```

Could someone please help me tweak it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried it in C# but VBA in Excel but it might be helpful. I have also changed double to single quotea. Anyway, here is the regexp

Text:

**/Update setting0 value='new value' /Save**

Regexp:

```
('{1}(\w|\s|:|\\|\.)+'{1}|\w)+
```

Result:

**Update**

**setting0**

**value**

**'new value'**

**Save**

Text:

**/Import 'C:\path\file.xml' 'C:\path_2\file_2.xml' /Exit**

Result:

**Import**

**'C:\path\file.xml'**

**'C:\path_2\file_2.xml'**

**Exit**

Comment: This works perfectly once I replaced the single quotes with doubles in the expression. Thank you for such a concise solution!

Comment: ('{1}(\w|\s|:|\\|\.)+'{1}|(/|\w))+  this version should return \Import instead of Import. I have just changed \w to (/|\w) at the end of the regexp.

Comment: Hah yeah I had just made one tweak to this that does the same and tested it: ...|(/?\w)+

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that cannot in general be solved using regular expressions. Instead, you can write a simple parser which takes a line, reading each character, then when it encounters a space and not being inside a quote, it takes the current substring and adds it to a list:

```
public static string[] ParseLine(string line)
        {
            var insideQuotes = false;

            var parts = new List<string>();

            var j = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
            {
                switch (line[i])
                {
                    case '"':
                         insideQuotes = !insideQuotes;
                         break;
                    case ' ':
                         if (!insideQuotes)
                         {
                             parts.Add(line.Substring(j, i - j));
                             j = i + 1;
                         }
                         break;
                    default:
                         continue;
                }
            }

            return parts.ToArray();
        }
```

Note however that this won't handle like escaped quotes inside quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This one works if there is even number of double quotes and no escaped quotes:

```
^
\s*
(?:
    (?:
        ([^\s"]+)
        |
        "([^"]*)"
    )
    \s*
)+
$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var matches = Regex.Matches("/Update setting0 value=\"new value\" /Save", "\\G(?:(\"[^\"]*\"?|[^ \"]+)|[ ]+)");

foreach (Match match in matches) {
    foreach (Capture capture in match.Groups[1].Captures) {
        Console.WriteLine(capture);
    }
}
```

If you want to not have the quotes (so `"new value"` becomes `new value`)

```
var matches = Regex.Matches("/Update setting0 value=\"new value\" /Save", "\\G(?:\"(?<1>[^\"]*)\"?|(?<1>[^ \"]+)|[ ]+)");
```

The `?` after the second `\"` is to catch unclosed quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Just my modified version of what `eulerfx` posted.  This one:

Should produce the results requested in the original question (so is "on topic").

Doesn't include quotes in the results

Doesn't include white-space only in results

Splits results on any white-space not inside quotes

Handles missing end-quote by just adding whatever is left-over after loop

Trims results, unless inside quotes.

I mostly made this for parsing the last 2 parts of each line of an IMAP list result.

```
    public static string[] ParseLine(string line)
    {
        var insideQuotes = false;
        var start = -1;

        var parts = new List<string>();

        for (var i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(line[i]))
            {
                if (!insideQuotes)
                {
                    if (start != -1)
                    {
                        parts.Add(line.Substring(start, i - start));
                        start = -1;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (line[i] == '"')
            {
                if (start != -1)
                {
                    parts.Add(line.Substring(start, i - start));
                    start = -1;
                }
                insideQuotes = !insideQuotes;
            }
            else
            {
                if (start == -1)
                    start = i;
            }
        }

        if (start != -1)
            parts.Add(line.Substring(start));

        return parts.ToArray();
    }
```