# Split string at space not inside quotes in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, split, space

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular Expression to split on spaces unless in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554013/regular-expression-to-split-on-spaces-unless-in-quotes)

I need to split a specified string at all spaces in order to get arguments, however, I need all the text inside quotes to stay "un-split". For example:

ab "c d"

This needs to be split into 2 strings: 1. ab, 2. "c d". I attempted to use regex or write my own method to parse it, but had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a duplicate as Bala R mentioned above.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\w+|""[\w\s]*""");
var str = "ab \"c d\"";

var x = regex.Matches(str).Cast<Match>().ToList();
```