# C# RegEx to create string array split on spaces and phrases (in quotes)

Tags: c#, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular Expression to split on spaces unless in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554013/regular-expression-to-split-on-spaces-unless-in-quotes)

I am dealing with various strings that I need to split into an array wherever there is a space, except for if that space exists within "quotes".

So for example, I would like this:

```
this is "a simple" test
```

..to become:

```
[0] = this
[1] = is
[2] = "a simple"
[3] = test
```

Note I would like to retain the quotes surrounding the phrase, not remove them.

Comment: Apologies! Those comma's should not have been in there - I've removed them from the question now. Thanks for highlighting that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex:

```
".*?"|[^\s]+
```

Usage:

```
String input = @"this is ""a simple"" test";
String[] matches =
    Regex.Matches(input, @""".*?""|[^\s]+").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
```