# RegEx to split string using space when not surrounded by quotes works in refiddle but not in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using the followin RegEx which I found in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554013/regular-expression-to-split-on-spaces-unless-in-quotes):
`/[^\s"]+|"[^"]*"/g`

I want to split the string by spaces except when strings are quoted by double quotes. The quotes have to be included by the result.

This is my C# code:

```
MatchCollection conditions = Regex.Matches(strCondition, @"/[^\s""]+|""[^""]*""/g");
```

conditions.Count is always zero!
When I test the regex online, it works!

Example input:

```
"0" MATCHES NOCASE "Den Bosch"  OR "0" MATCHES NOCASE "'s Hertogenbosch"

"0" MATCHES "1" AND "1" MATCHES "2" AND "2" MATCHES "3" AND "3" MATCHES "4" AND "4" MATCHES "5"
```

What am I doing wrong? I wasted several hours and have no clue anymore.

This one: `(?<=")\w[\w\s]*(?=")|\w+|"[\w\s]*"` does give results in my case, but does not give the desired result because it fails on single quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular expressions in .NET don't use the `/` delimiters, so:

```
MatchCollection conditions = Regex.Matches(strCondition, @"[^\s""]+|""[^""]*""");
```

Comment: Fantastic! I knew it had to be something small. Thank you very much now I think I can finish it before the deadline.