# C# Regular Expression which excludes characters inside Quotes

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I am trying to split a line into a key / value pair by using Regex. Can anyone give me a hint on how to split the line below properly?

The line looks like this:

```
"key"="some=value"
```

I'd like to split it into:

```
key  
some=value
```

I have to read an string resource file, which looks like this:

```
"key1"="translation number one";  
"key2"="translation number = the second number";
```

When I do a

```
string[] elements = Regex.Slit(line, "=");
```

I get 3 elements instead of the 2 I want. So basically I want to Split at the "=" outside the quotes

Comment: Can you please share your code? Where exactly are you getting stuck?

Comment: `mystring.Split('\"');` returns `string[]`, elements 1 and 3 contain values you want. No need for regex here.

Comment: alwayes you have the same line the key alwayes empty and = after " ?

Comment: I have to read an string resource file, which looks like this:

    `code`"key1"="translation number 1";  
    "key2"="translation number = the second number";  

When I do a  
    Regex.Slit(line, "=")  
I get 3 elemtens instead of the two I want. So basically I want to Split at the "=" outside the quotes

Comment: Split on `"="` then replace `^"` and `"$` with nothing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular Expression to split on spaces unless in quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554013/regular-expression-to-split-on-spaces-unless-in-quotes)

Comment: First of all, why would you ever want to do this?  This is basically a JSON string, so why not just use the built in deserialization methods of C#?  You're basically trying to create a serializer.

Comment: @user1477388 since when json has `=` as a key-value delimiter?

Comment: @Anri It would be easier to just convert your equal signs (that are outside of the double quotes) to colons and be done with it.

Comment: You're trying to interpret it as a key/value pair with double quote delimeters, when in fact you don't give any hint of quoting rules. Quoting rules are delimiters that must have provision for escaping a delimiter constant, otherwise quoting is an invalid concept.

Answer (score 1):

First strip the string for quote(`"`) for both ends. Then split the string using regex:

```
string []splits = Regex.Split(input.Trim('"'), "\\s*\"\\s*=\\s*\"\\s*");
```

Comment: What if your data has escaped quotes?  Why not just use the built in deserialization methods in C#?

Answer (score 0):

Assumes single key=value per line

```
^"(?<key>[^"]+)"="(?<value>.*)"$
```

Comment: What if a string contains a quote?

Comment: @SimonBelanger  I believe this is greedy by default, but just in case, we can make it specific...

Comment: I realised after putting my comment that this might be the case, especially with `^` and `$`. Explicitely handling escaping characters for quotes is as simple as `(?<value>([^"]|\\")+)`.