# PHP Regex: Split by spaces that are not in quotes

Tags: php, regex

How would one split a string in php by spaces that are not enclosed within double quotes? For example, this:

```
"hello my \"name is bob\""
```

Would become this:

```
["hello", "my", "\"name is bob\""]
```

Comment: can you give an example

Comment: by parsing the string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/554068/2534876 maybe this is helpful

Answer (score 2):

You can use this pettern: `/\s(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/`
String can be long as you want, quotes may be escaped or unescaped.
This: `"hello my \"name is bob\" hello my \"name is john\" end"` or this `'hello my "name is bob" hello my "name is john" end'` is possible.

Example of usage:

```
$array = preg_split('/\s(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/', "hello my \"name is bob\" hello my \"name is john\" end");
```

Comment: This is the only solution on this page that worked for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this function based on a regular expression:

```
function splitNonQuoted($data) {
    preg_match_all('/\S*?(".*?"\S*?)*( |$)/', $data, $matches);
    array_pop($matches[0]);
    return $matches[0];
}
```

Example use:

```
print_r (splitNonQuoted("hello my \"name is bob\""));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello 
    [1] => my 
    [2] => "name is bob"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution with `preg_split` just for your particular case:

```
$words = preg_split('/(?!\\"\w+?)\s+(?!\w+\s*?\w*\\"\Z)/', "hello my \"name is bob\"");
var_dump($words);

// output:
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "hello"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "my"
  [2]=>
  string(13) ""name is bob""
}
```