# Split a string based on spaces (unless in quotes) and remove the quotes afterwards

Tags: c#, regex, split

I'm using the below code to split a string based on spaces, unless that space happens inside quotation marks. How can I remove the quotation marks from the final result?

```
var txt = "PROGRAM \"My ETABS\" VERSION \"9.7.4\"";

string[] split = Regex.Matches(txt, "(\\w+|\".*?\")")
                      .Cast<Match>()
                      .Select(m => m.Value)
                      .ToArray();
```

**Now I have this:**

```
PROGRAM
"My ETABS"
VERSION
"9.7.4"
```

**But I want this:**

```
PROGRAM  
My ETABS
VERSION 
9.7.4
```

Comment: `.Select(m => m.Value).Replace("\"", "")`?

Comment: I don't think you applied this: *unless that space happens inside quotation marks*

Comment: @revo Sorry revo, I fixed it.

Comment: Try this: [`"([^"]+)"|(\S+)`](https://www.regex101.com/r/xfkmq3/1)

Comment: also the second answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554013/regular-expression-to-split-on-spaces-unless-in-quotes?rq=1