# How can I split command line text into tokens that might contain spaces?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am writing a C# console app that mimics a CLI.
Let's assume the only thing this app can do is change directory `cd`.

Example: once the following command is entered:

```
> cd some_folder
```

the the app will try to change current working directory to `some_folder`.
To avoid dealing with white-space, I am splitting the command by SPACE character and end up with a string array of "tokens".

```cs
 string command = Console.ReadLine();
 string[] tokens = command.Split(' ');

          // tokens[0] -> "cd"
          // tokens[1] -> "some_folder"
```

This is all fine. The only issue I am facing is if the folder name contains spaces.

```
cd "another folder"
```

If I split by SPACE character, I would end up with 3 tokens, instead of only 2.
I could split by SPACE then re-construct the folder name depending if it contains double qoutes or not, but I am sure there is a better solution.

What is the best way to split the command text into tokens, knowing that sometimes the second token can be encapsulated in between double quotes?

I tried the following regex

```
  \w+\s+(".*?"|[^"]*?)
```

but that would assume that I must have 2 tokens at all times, which might not be the case.

Comment: The _best_ solution here would be to use a proper string tokenizer, which can consume doubly quoted terms properly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Regex Split - commas outside quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147836/c-sharp-regex-split-commas-outside-quotes) its for commas instead of spaces but the logic should be the same

Comment: FYI .net already has a [System.CommandLine](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.CommandLine) package, and you can learn how it parses a string: [code](https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api/blob/2.0.0-beta4.22272.1/src/System.CommandLine/Parsing/CommandLineStringSplitter.cs#L35)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular Expression to split on spaces unless in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554013/regular-expression-to-split-on-spaces-unless-in-quotes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter command:");
        string command = Console.ReadLine();
        string pattern = @"[^\s""]+|""[^""]*""";

        var matches = Regex.Matches(command, pattern);

        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            string token = match.Value;
            // Remove double quotes from the token if it's encapsulated.
            token = token.StartsWith("\"") && token.EndsWith("\"") ? token[1..^1] : token;
            Console.WriteLine($"Token: {token}");
        }
    }
}
```

Let's break down the regex pattern used:

> [^\s"]+

matches one or more characters that are not whitespace **(\s)** or double quotes **(")**. This part of the pattern matches unquoted tokens.

> "[^"]*"

matches a double-quoted string: it starts with a double quote, followed by zero or more characters that are not double quotes **([^"]*)**, and ends with a double quote. This part of the pattern matches tokens that are enclosed in double quotes.

Using this regex pattern ensures that your application can flexibly parse commands, regardless of the number of tokens or whether some tokens contain spaces and are enclosed in double quotes.

Great guide on [regex](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html)

Comment: Excellent. Only one issue though: `token[1..^1]` is this python? or is it a feature of C#12?

Comment: @Ahmad it was added in a C# 8.0 you can read about it in the range page of the C# documentation 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges

Answer (score 0):

A more naive solution, not as fancy as the other ones (does not include a regex), would be to simply take the command first, then take the remaining of the string as "arguments", and parse them, if needed, depending on the command. One possible solution would look like this:

```
using System;
                
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var cmd1 = "cd my folder";
        var cmd2 = "ls";
    
        var parsedCmd1 = ParseCommand(cmd1);
        var parsedCmd2 = ParseCommand(cmd2);
    
        if (parsedCmd1.Command.Equals("cd", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            var folderName = parsedCmd1.Arguments;
            Console.WriteLine($"Command: [cd], Folder Name: [{folderName}]");
        }
        else if (parsedCmd1.Command.Equals("ls", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Command: [ls], no arguments");
        }
        // else if () // other commands would fall here
    }

    private static ParsedCommand ParseCommand(string input)
    {
        var firstSpaceIndex = input.IndexOf(' ');
    
        if (firstSpaceIndex >= 0)
        {
            var cmd = input.Substring(0, firstSpaceIndex);
            var arguments = input.Substring(firstSpaceIndex + 1);
        
            return new ParsedCommand
            {
                Command = cmd,
                Arguments = arguments
            };
        }
    
        return new ParsedCommand
        {
            Command = input,
            Arguments = string.Empty
        };
    }
}

public class ParsedCommand
{
    public string Command { get; set; }
    public string Arguments { get; set; }
}
```

While I know (as I have already stated) that this is not the best solution, it is a possible approach, it is easier to understand what happens within the code. It won't need a regex change if you decide to add more complexity/other commands. Furthermore, you can include the logic for each command (for instance what you are going to do with the folder name if you know it is a `cd` command) in a specialized class.