# Java regex split on whitespace not preceded or followed by single or double quotes

Tags: java, regex, split, quotes

I can't get this to work..

I have an String which I want to split on spaces. However, I do not want to split inside Strings. That is, text which is inside double or single quotes.

Example

Splitting the following string:

```
private String words = " Hello, today is nice " ;
```

..should produce the following tokens:

```
 private
 String
 words
 =
 " Hello, today is nice "
 ;
```

What kind of regex can I use for this?

Comment: Shouldn't this work?
"[^\\s\"']+|\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'"

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366202/regex-for-splitting-a-string-using-space-when-not-surrounded-by-single-or-double)

Comment: was looking at it but thought it was different. now i realize it's the same question. sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex `([^ "]*)|("[^"]*")` should match all the tokens. Drawing on my limited knowledge of Java and http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html, you should be able to do something like this:

```
// Please excuse any syntax errors, I'm used to C#
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^ \"]*)|(\"[^\"]*\")");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(theString);
while (matcher.find())
{
    // do something with matcher.group();
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. This was suitable for my application and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
((['"]).*?\2|\S+)
```

Here is what it does:

```
(         <= Group everything
  (['"])  <= Find a simple or double quote
  .*?     <= Capture everything after the quote (ungreedy)
  \2      <= Find the simple or double quote (same as we had before)
  |       <= Or
  \S+     <= Non space characters (one at least)
)
```

---

On another note, if you want to create a parser, do a parser and don't use regexes.

Comment: Tried this.. but it doesn't extract any tokens at all for some reason.. perhaps not suitable for the split method?
 
String[] tokens = myString.get(x).split("((['\"]).*?\\2|\\S+)");