# Regular Express to replace instances of character, but NOT inside brackets

Tags: java, regex

I am needing a bit of assistance in a regular expression I am trying to create, I am usually pretty good with these but this one has me stuck...

I am needing to replace the number 9 in strings on the fly with \d (creating a new regular expression).  These are some example strings that can be expected:

```
X(29)

9(5)

99

X(29)V999S
```

Now before you answer too quickly, we must not touch the numbers in the brackets...
I have looked at a couple of other answers on here and there is probably something in this solution, but I cannot seem to adapt it - [Regex for splitting a string using space when not surrounded by single or double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366202/regex-for-splitting-a-string-using-space-when-not-surrounded-by-single-or-double)

So far I have come up with

```
line.replaceAll("[^(\\d)]??9[^)]??", "\\d");
```

which gives me

```
X(2\d)

\d(5)

\d\d

X(2\d)V\d\d\dS
```

Anyone have any thoughts.

Comment: I believe I have worked it out!
line.replaceAll("9(?![\\d]*\\))", "\\d")

Basically it says the 9 is replaceable as long as it does not have a closing bracket after it...

it accounts for 9(999), which I bet will turn up at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
(?!\([^\(]*)9(?![^\(]*\))
```

Comment: I cannot post my answer for 8hrs, so until then your answer will suffice for anyone looking for similar, and alternative is line.replaceAll("9(?![\\d]*\))", "\\d")

Answer (score 2):

given that your rules are pretty straight-forward but just difficult to implement with regular expressions, why not do-it-yourself? Iterate over the string and create a new string keeping track of the state (in brackets or out).

Barry

Comment: +1 for this suggestion. The regular expression given by Michael probably works, but it's not **obvious** how it works. A simple loop would be clear and easy to understand.