# java Regex - split but ignore text inside quotes?

Tags: java, regex

using only regular expression methods, the method String.replaceAll and ArrayList
how can i split a String into tokens, but ignore delimiters that exist inside quotes? 
the delimiter is any character that is not alphanumeric or quoted text

for example:
The string :

> hello^world'this*has two tokens'

should output:

> - hello
> - worldthis*has two tokens

Comment: You know what your delimiter looks like, so you don't need a regex, you need to split the string on the delimiter.  Use the right tool for the right job.

Comment: I don't know, the delimiter can be any char that is not alphanum

Comment: Then your problem is ill-formed.  Decide what your delimiter is and then split the string accordingly.

Comment: @babybang: What should happen if the input contains an unmatched quote? Why are the quotes missing in your expected output?

Comment: @JackManey: This problem is not "ill-formed". Slightly underspecified, yes, but it's much better specified than most questions on here.

Comment: It's completely unanswerable as stated. "I want to split a string."  "On what?" "Ummm...stuff."

Comment: split it on whatever you like...

Comment: The problem is that the resulting array **depends on the pattern upon which the string is split**.

Comment: Of course every string split will have some pattern. Here pattern is that split it on any non-alphanumeric delimiter if that non-alphanumeric delimiter is not inside a pair of single quotes. IMO it is good problem to solve and regex is best tool to solve this. Please check @MarkByers and my answers on using 2 different flavors of regex to get same results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex for splitting a string using space when not surrounded by single or double quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366202/regex-for-splitting-a-string-using-space-when-not-surrounded-by-single-or-double)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) to identify the parts you want to keep, rather than the parts you want to split on:

```
String s = "hello^world'this*has two tokens'";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9]+|'[^']*')+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/Uxa5e)

Answer (score 5):

I know there is a damn good and accepted answer already present but I would like to add another regex based (and may I say simpler) approach to split the given text using any non-alphanumeric delimiter which not inside the single quotes using

**Regex:**

```
/(?=(([^']+'){2})*[^']*$)[^a-zA-Z\\d]+/
```

Which basically means match a non-alphanumeric text if it is **followed by even number of single quotes** in other words match a non-alphanumeric text if it is outside single quotes.

**Code:**

```
String string = "hello^world'this*has two tokens'#2ndToken";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(
     string.split("(?=(([^']+'){2})*[^']*$)[^a-zA-Z\\d]+"))
);
```

**Output:**

```
[hello, world'this*has two tokens', 2ndToken]
```

**Demo:**

[**`Here is a live working Demo of the above code.`**](http://ideone.com/xmDsU)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot in any reasonable way. You are posing a problem that regular expressions aren't good at.

Comment: I have a great deal of belief in the definition of a regular expression. See Jack Maney's comment.

Comment: If you think regular expressions are unsuitable for this, could you at least show an alternative/better approach? This answer won't help the OP (or anyone else) unless you can suggest something better.

Comment: The OK said, "Using only regular expressions." I'm happy to upvote your answer, but I don't respond to questions like that beyond answering the literal question.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use a regular expression for this. It won't work. Use / write a parser instead.

You should use the right tool for the right task.