# Selecting URLs using RegExp but ignoring them when surrounded by double quotes

Tags: regex, url, quote

I've searched around quite a bit now, but I can't get any suggestions to work in my situation. I've seen success with negative lookahead or lookaround, but I really don't understand it.

I wish to use RegExp to find URLs in blocks of text but ignore them when quoted. While not perfect yet I have the following to find URLs:

```
(https?\://)?(\w+\.)+\w{2,}(:[0-9])?\/?((/?\w+)+)?(\.\w+)?
```

I want it to match the following:

```
www.test.com:50/stuff
http://player.vimeo.com/video/63317960
odd.name.amazone.com/pizza
```

But not match:

```
"www.test.com:50/stuff
http://plAyerz.vimeo.com/video/63317960"
"odd.name.amazone.com/pizza"
```

---

**Edit:**

To clarify, I could be passing a full paragraph of text through the expression. Sample paragraph of what I'd like below:

I would like the following link to be found **[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)**. However this link should be ignored **"www.example.com"**. It would be nice, but not required, to have **"www.example.com** and **www.example.com"** ignored as well.

A sample of a different one I have working below. language is php:

```
$articleEntry = "Hey guys! Check out this cool video on Vimeo: player.vimeo.com/video/63317960";

$pattern = array('/\n+/', '/(https?\:\/\/)?(player\.vimeo\.com\/video\/[0-9]+)/');
                    
$replace = array('<br/><br/>',
    '<iframe src="http://$2?color=40cc20" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>'); 
    $articleEntry = preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$articleEntry);
```

The result of the above will replace any new lines "\n" with a double break "
" and will embed the Vimeo video by replacing the Vimeo address with an iframe and link.

Comment: What language are you using this in?

Comment: In the don't match URL examples you have listed, isn't here a mistake in the first and second URLs. I can only see one quote ?

Comment: I'm using php's preg_replace. @Sniffer I guess I'm trying to say that I don't want a match if there is a quote at the begining, end or both. I'll post in more code example to be more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution!

```
(?=(([^"]+"){2})*[^"]*$)((https?:\/\/)?(\w+\.)+\w{2,}(:[0-9]+)?((\/\w+)+(\.\w+)?)?\/?)
```

The first part from (? to *$) what makes it work for me. I found this as an answer in [java Regex - split but ignore text inside quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864537/) by https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava

While I had read that question before, I had overlooked his answer because it wasn't the one that "solved" the question. I just changed the single quote to double quote and it works out for me.

Comment: It worked well for me, thank you so much!

this is my resulting expression:
/(?=(([^"]+"){2})*[^"]*$)(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim

(?=(([^"]+"){2})*[^"]*$) - that what you suggested and second part is to detect url for my case.

Answer (score 0):

add `^` and `$` to your regex

```
 ^(https?\://)?(\w+\.)+\w{2,}(:[0-9])?\/?((/?\w+)+)?(\.\w+)?$
```

please notice you might need to escape the slashes after http (meaning `https?\:\/\/`)

*update*

if you want it to be case sensitive, you shouldn't use `\w` but `[a-z]`. the \w contains all letters and numbers, so you should be careful while using it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I wasn't very clear before. I'm passing a full paragraph of text with a URL somewhere inside. Correct me if I'm wrong, but will the anchors only find a match with nothing around the URL? I'm do want to allow case sensitive URLs. Bit.ly for example requires it. So far my parser is happy with escaping the colon and slashes. But I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: if you only want to ignore the ", add ^\" (or ^", depending on language) before and after, if you also want to be case sensitive (in your example - player and not plAyer), replace \w with [a-z]

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still struggling with this. By adding ^\" or ^" it won't match any URL regardless if there are or are not double quotes.