# String to arguments

Tags: java

Let's say I have a string like `function arg1 arg2 "arg3 is long"`.

How could I obtain the output of

```
String[0] = "function"
String[1] = "arg1"
String[2] = "arg2"
String[3] = "arg is long"
```

Comment: What would you want the output to be from that example?

Comment: A String[] with the contents of String[0] = "function"; String[1] = "arg1"; etc

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex for splitting a string using space when not surrounded by single or double quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366202/regex-for-splitting-a-string-using-space-when-not-surrounded-by-single-or-double)

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Restate it in brief and to the point.

Answer (score 1):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367706/is-there-a-good-command-line-argument-parser-for-java)'s answer has a number of options for you to explore, but they are tailored for real command-line arguments.

- [Apache Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/cli/)
- [JSAP](http://www.martiansoftware.com/jsap/)
- [Args4J](http://args4j.kohsuke.org)
- [JCommander](http://jcommander.org)
- Roll your own with [Scanner](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).