# Regex to tokenize string in java with space and double quotes

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to create a regex to tokenize a string. An example string would be.

```
"hello world" Alexandros Alex "I Am" Something
```

I need to get responce back:

```
hello world
Alexandros
Alex 
I am
Something
```

So to make it clear, tokenize with space but not words within quotes.
If this is an easy regural expresion sorry in advance but i always strugle with these.

Comment: Your expected response here seems to just be your expression without quotes.

In that case, you could just do a replace using [\"]

Comment: @LorcanO'Neill: No, look at _hello world_ and _I am_.

Comment: @LorcanO'Neill OP wants 5 output strings / tokens for the input example, not just the `"expression without quotes"`.

Comment: What happens with nested quotes? `"\"hello world\"" for example" Alexandros Alex "I Am" Something`

Comment: What is your expected result for the string `@#$@#%234 jkher@#$` or the string `jhkasd "asdsad` (quote not closed)?

Comment: His output does not make that obvious. Your explanation does.

Would it have been that hard to show your output like this? 

hello world, Alexandros, Alex, I am, Something

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366202/regex-for-splitting-a-string-using-space-when-not-surrounded-by-single-or-double?rq=1

Comment: @Lorcan O'Neill, sorry, did not think it was not obvious, but you people have a point.

Comment: @nhahtdh i do not really care, i liked answer of matts, but something i forgot to mention is that i need to allow *,?,_ characters inside, seems like davidrac gave an easier to understand answer which also covers the last requirement that did not previously cover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try: `\b(?:(?<=")[^"]*(?=")|\w+)\b`.  This will exclude the actual quotes from the matches.

```
import java.util.regex.*;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String...args) {
        String line = "\"hello world\" Alexandros Alex \"I Am\" Something";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b(?:(?<=\")[^\"]*(?=\")|\\w+)\\b");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
        }
    }
}
```

When executed, you get this output:

```
$ javac Test.java
$ java Test
hello world
Alexandros
Alex
I Am
Something
```

Comment: +1 @matts working fine but a brief description of regex would be appreciated

Comment: Hello matts,
Something i just noticed, but forgot to mention, perhaps since you gave me an olmost perfect answer you can assist me on the following extra requirement
words may have ?, *, _ inside
so i.e. could be 
"hello * world?" Alexandros Alex "I Am *" Something
and would like to get:
hello * world?
Alexandros 
Alex 
I Am*
Something

Comment: @Alexandros The regex should already match special characters inside the quotes, though to match special characters in the non-quoted words, you'll have to change the `\\w` to a character class like `[\\w\\?\\*\\_]`, which will match any word character and any of the escaped special characters.

Comment: How would you modify it to match single quotes instead of double?

Comment: @Yuki1112 replace the three double quotes in the regex with single quotes

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression will match either words or entire strings within quotes: `"[^"]*"|\w*`

You can create a matcher with this regex and just iterate through all the matches. You can find some sample code [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Comment: but its matching `" " ` as well, and OP wants doesnt want these quotes in output

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **split**,you can do so by checking if `"` are balanced..

Now obviously if the space is between `""` the number of `"` would not be even..This is what the below `regex` do

```
\s(?=(?:([^"]*"[^"]*"[^"]*)*|[^"]*)$)
```

Comment: What he has in the question is a **sample** string. Your regex is only going to work on his sample string only. It will fail when there are more quoted strings.

Comment: @nhahtdh have you even tested..it **works** even when there are nested `"`..don't assume..place your reason with **facts** not **if**

Comment: @nhahtdh i had missed `*`..works perfectly now..thx to point it out