# Regex splitting string using space in key/value pairs not surrounded by quotes

Tags: java, regex, split

I'm struggling with finding the right regex for parsing a string containing key/value pairs.
The string should be split on space when not surrounded by double quotes.

Example string:

```
2013-10-26    15:16:38:011+0200 name="twitter-message" from_user="MyUser" in_reply_to="null" start_time="Sat Oct 26 15:16:21 CEST 2013" event_id="394090123278974976" text="Some text" retweet_count="1393"
```

Desired output should be

```
2013-10-26
15:16:38:011+0200
name="twitter-message"
from_user="MyUser" 
in_reply_to="null" 
start_time="Sat Oct 26 15:16:21 CEST 2013" 
event_id="394090123278974976" 
text="Some text" 
retweet_count="1393"
```

I found this answer to get me near the desired result  [Regex for splitting a string using space when not surrounded by single or double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366202/regex-for-splitting-a-string-using-space-when-not-surrounded-by-single-or-double) 
with regex :

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[^\\s\"']+|\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'").matcher(str);
        while (m.find())
            list.add(m.group());
```

This gives a list of:

```
2013-10-26
15:16:38:011+0200
name=
"twitter-message"
from_user=
"MyUser"
in_reply_to=
"null"
start_time=
"Sat Oct 26 15:16:21 CEST 2013"
event_id=
"394090123278974976"
text=
"Some text"
retweet_count=
"1393"
```

It splits on = sign so there is still something missing to get to the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try maybe with this

```
[^\\s=]+(=\"[^\"]+\")?
```

- `[^\\s=]+` will find everything that is not space or `=` so for `start_time="Sat Oct 26 15:16:21 CEST 2013"` it will match `start_time` part.
- `(=\"[^\"]+\")?` is optional and it will match `="zzz"` part (where `z` can't be `"`)

Example

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[^\\s=]+(=\"[^\"]+\")?").matcher(str);
while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

Output:

```
2013-10-26
15:16:38:011+0200
name="twitter-message"
from_user="MyUser"
in_reply_to="null"
start_time="Sat Oct 26 15:16:21 CEST 2013"
event_id="394090123278974976"
text="Some text"
retweet_count="1393"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: `Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?:[^\\s\"']|\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*')+").matcher(str);`

Your original regex could be understood as "match either a series of non-whitespace characters, or a quoted string".  This one is "match a series of either non-whitespace characters or quoted strings".

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
// if your string is str

// split on space if followed by even number of quotes
String[] arr = str.split(" +(?=(?:([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)");
for (String s: arr)
   System.out.printf("%s%n", s);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
2013-10-26
15:16:38:011+0200
name="twitter-message"
from_user="MyUser" 
in_reply_to="null" 
start_time="Sat Oct 26 15:16:21 CEST 2013" 
event_id="394090123278974976" 
text="Some text" 
retweet_count="1393"
```