# How to split string not showing anything in double or single quotes?

Tags: regex, perl-data-structures

I get lines from the text file and then need to split them into words. So eveything in single or double quotes should be ignored.
For example:  **use line; "$var", print 'comment': "get 'comment % two'"** 
should be inserted in an array as  **use, line, print** . All other just ignored.
Also I need to check if % sitting inside single or double quotes (like in the above example)

`my @array = $file_line =~ /[\$A-z_]{2,}/g;` gives all the words (plus anything that contains $) but I can't not to ignore characters in the quotes

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex for splitting a string using space when not surrounded by single or double quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366202/regex-for-splitting-a-string-using-space-when-not-surrounded-by-single-or-double)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the answer that you can first remove the quoted words
using

```
$line =~ s/ ( ["'] ) .*? \1 //xg;
```

However, you should be aware that your regular expression

```
[\$A-z_]
```

picks up all the ASCII characters between 'A' and 'z', in particular,
the following punctuation characters:

```
[ \ ] ^ _ `
```

So you should either be more explicit in your regular expression

```
[\$A-Za-z_]
```

or you should add the case-insensitive flag "i" to your substitution
and just use one case in the regular expression:

```
$file_line =~ /[\$A-Z_]{2,}/gi;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first remove all the quoted words, for example using:

```
$line =~ s/ ( ["'] ) .*? \1 //xg;
```

You might want to slightly change it depending on how you want to handle nested quotes, unclosed quotes etc.