# how to decipher a variable for running a command

Tags: python

I am trying to run the command "tool --server=commander.company.com runProcedure Android_Main --procedureName priority_kw --actualParameter priority_changes="769373 769374" gerrit_server=review-android.company.com" using below code,
trying to put the value in variable "var" but not able to ?can anyone suggest what should be changed in below code to run the above command?

```
var = "769373 769374"

#tool --server=commander.company.com runProcedure Android_Main --procedureName priority_kw --actualParameter priority_changes="769373 769374" gerrit_server=review-android.company.com
cmd = "tool --server=commander.company.com runProcedure Android_Main --procedureName priority_kw --actualParameter priority_changes=\"{0}\" gerrit_server=review-android.company.com".format(var)

Pipe = Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
(output, error) = Pipe.communicate()
print output
print error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `split` your command, you're separating the two parts of "769373 769374". Just write out the list yourself instead of using `split`:

```
cmd = ['tool', '--server=commander.company.com', 'runProcedure', 'Android_Main',
       '--procedureName', 'priority_kw', '--actualParameter',
       'priority_changes="769373 769374"',
       'gerrit_server=review-android.company.com']

Pipe = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

If you still want to split automatically, you can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366202/regex-for-splitting-a-string-using-space-when-not-surrounded-by-single-or-double) for splitting the string correctly using regular expressions.

Comment: where to put the variable "Var" in cmd ?

Comment: @user3654069 You could change the expression `'priority_changes="769373 769374"'` to `'priority_changes="{}"'.format(var)`.