# Javascript|node.js regex|function for converting Bioware .2da table row to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, node.js

I want to return an array for a table-row string like:

```
'31 Chicken   2013  "Chi cken"    12.345   ****'
```

to an array: `["Chicken", 2013, "Chi cken", 12.345, null]`

- The columns in the table are defined by any number of one or more spaces (non-tab) between entries. (Entries which contain spaces are
  enclosed in double quotes and cannot contain quotes themselves.)
- The first column is always an integer, which can be discarded, so that the array begins with second column.
- Entry can be an integer, float or string.
- 4 consecutive asterisks **** denote a null value.

Any help?

(link to fuller format info: https://github.com/xoreos/xoreos-docs/blob/master/specs/bioware/2DA_Format.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took some of KRONWALLED's suggestion and a regex from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366202/regex-for-splitting-a-string-using-space-when-not-surrounded-by-single-or-double). Couldn't figure out how to get quotes from being added to matched strings.

```
var str = '31 Chicken    2013 "Chi cken" 12.345 ****';
console.log(str);
var tmp = str.match(/[^\s"']+|"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)'/g);
console.log(tmp);
var n;
tmp.shift();
for (i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
  str = tmp[i];
  if (str === "****") {
    tmp[i] = null;
  }
  else if (str.startsWith('"')) {
    n = str.lastIndexOf('"');
    tmp[i] = str.slice(1,n); 
    }
  else {
    n = Number(str);
    if(isNaN(n)){
      //console.log(str + " NaN")
    }
    else tmp[i] = n;
  }

}
console.log(tmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write a parser which covers your example.

Working example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rr2sz4m7/)

```
for (i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
  if (i == 0) continue;
  else if (tmp[i] === "****") {
    output.push("null");
    continue;
  }
  else if (tmp[i].startsWith('"')) {
    output.push(tmp[i] + ' ' + tmp[i + 1]);
    i++;
    continue;
    }
  else {
    output.push(tmp[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the regex for the six matches,
you can then forget the item `[0]` and convert the last one to `null` (when ****)

```
[0-9\.0-9]+|[a-zA-Z0-9]+|\"[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+\"|\*\*\*\*
```