# Split a Javascript by space, unless between quotes--but without matching the quotes themselves

Tags: javascript, regex

This is slight variant of a common question: how do you split a string by whitespace, unless that whitespace is contained within a pair of quotes (either " or ')? There are a lot of questions like this here, and the best answer I've found so far is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/366532/1255372). The problem is, all these answer include the quotes themselves in the matches. For instance:

```
"foo bar 'i went to a bar'".match(/[^\s"']+|"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)'/g);
```

Results in:

```
["foo", "bar", "'i went to a bar'"]
```

Is there a solution that results in:

```
["foo", "bar", "i went to a bar"]
```

Note there is an edge case around this:

```
"foo bar \"'Hi,' she said, 'how are you?'\"".match(...);
=> // ["foo", "bar", "'Hi,' she said, 'how are you?'"]
```

That is to say, a substring should be able to include quotations of its own, which means that aggressively doing something like this won't work:

```
"foo bar \"'Hi,' she said, 'how are you?'\"".match(...).map(function(string) {
  return string.replace(/'|"/g, '');
});
```

Update:

We can basically get it working with this:

```
"foo bar \"'Hi,' she said, 'how are you?'\"".match(/[^\s"']+|"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)'/g).map(function(string) {
    return string.replace(/^('|")|('|")$/g, '');
});
```

But that's quite ugly. (And it will also break an edge case like "5ft 5feet 5'".) There's gotta be a way to shrink that to a single regex, right?

Comment: not using regex, but what if you just counted the number of `'` and if there are only two then you could use `.trim("'")` i doubt this is the solution - just getting ideas out there

Comment: Thanks for the idea! One edge case around this might be: `"foo bar \"my mother's bread\""`

Comment: Or rather: "foo bar \"mother's bread, father's lead\""

Comment: @AnthonyStringer That does give me an idea, though. I've got something working now (it's documented in the update above), but I still think there's gotta be a way to turn this into a single regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is good enough. You just need to loop through the matches and pick the **correct captured group**:

```js
var re = /'([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)'|"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"|[^\s"']+/g;
var arr = ['foo bar "\'Hi,\' she said, \'how are you?\'"',
  'foo bar \'i went to a bar\'',
  'foo bar \'"Hi," she said, "how are you?"\'',
  '\'"Hi," she \\\'said\\\', "how are you?"\''
];

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var m;
  var result = [];
  while ((m = re.exec(arr[i])) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex)
      re.lastIndex++;
    result.push(m[1] || m[2] || m[0])
  }
  console.log(result)
}
```

Comment: This works great! If I wanted to add escaped quotes, how would I do that? That is, how would we get this to work: `'\'"Hi," she \\\'said\\\', "how are you?"\''`

Comment: Escaped quotes can be supported but regex will become pretty complex. I will add an update to my answer in few hours when I get back to my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Quoted strings are always fun. You need to test for even or odd numbers of escape characters to know when to terminate the string.

```
function quotedSplit(str) {
    let re = /'((?:(?:(?:\\\\)*\\')|[^'])*)'|"((?:(?:(?:\\\\)*\\")|[^"])*)"|(\w+)/g,
        arr = [],
        m;
    while(m = re.exec(str))
        arr.push(m[1] || m[2] || m[3]);

    return arr;
}

quotedSplit("fizz 'foo \\'bar\\'' buzz" + ' --- ' + 'fizz "foo \\"bar\\"" buzz');
// ["fizz", "foo \'bar\'", "buzz", "fizz", "foo \"bar\"", "buzz"]
```

Here, the first two matches will find quoted strings, the third match is a "word"

Comment: This is interesting, but the `\w+` is a little limiting if I want to match symbols like '='.