# Regular expression to split based on spaces quotes and parenthesis

Tags: java, regex, split

I have question related to the following post
[Regex for splitting a string using space when not surrounded by single or double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366202/regex-for-splitting-a-string-using-space-when-not-surrounded-by-single-or-double)
Is there a way to split string when parenthesis is also involed

Input String -("This is My First String") Second Third
 Should split to
("This is My First String")
Second
Third

Input String - "This is My First String" Second Third 
should split to

"This is My First String"
Second
Third

Comment: **Please see [StackOverflow's Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)**

Answer (score 1):

You can escape parentheses in Regex using backslash.

Regex `\(a\)` will match exactly string `(a)`.

You can find more about special characters here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharacters.html

Or try out your regex with explanation here: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Adrian, Thank you. Can you post the full regex that satisfies all the condition.