# Split a string using multiple delimiters in java

Tags: java, regex, string, split, delimiter

I need to split a string base on two delimiters: one or more space and quote

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    String[] aStr = {"Header  \"2018-02-23 picture test\"", "Average Value \"A B \"  3.14"};

    for(String str: aStr) {
        for(String str1: str.split("\"|\\s"))
            System.out.println(str1);
    }
}
```

My desired output:

```
Header
2018-02-18 picture test
Average
Value
A B
3.14
```

Comment: why are "Average" and "Value" on different lines? Or why are "picture" and "test" not on different lines

Comment: I don't think you need to split on quotes... You need to group by matching  quotes

Comment: "picture" and "test" are inside a quote and "Average" and "Value" not.

Comment: Not applied split between quote

Comment: Then you do not want to split on *one or more space and quote*. You want to split on spaces, words *optionally enclosed in quotes*

Comment: It look like a `csv` with a specific delimiter (space). You can check for an API on this, good API knows how to treat quotes in a field.

Comment: Thanks for your comment with that, I found how to resolve it.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366202/regex-for-splitting-a-string-using-space-when-not-surrounded-by-single-or-double

Comment: Was gonna post this as an answer, but your question got closed... Try [this](https://regex101.com/r/r5oCFy/1/)