# How do I tokenize a string with quoted strings in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Tokens are separated by 1 or more spaces.
"A quoted string" is a single token.
Anything else not beginning with a quote is a token.
I tried and failed with:

```
var tokenre = /"[^"]*"|[^"]\S+|\s\s*/g;
```

For instance I want this input

```
[4,4]  "This is fun"
 2  2 +
 #
```

To tokenize as

```
['[4,4]', '  ', '"This is fun"', '\n ', '2', '  ', '2', ' ', '+', '\n ', '#']
```

This could be tested with the following code:

```
var result = null;
do {
    result = tokenre.exec (program);
    console.log (result);
} while (result != null);
```

Comment: While this is for Java, I think this question might be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366202/regex-for-splitting-a-string-using-space-when-not-surrounded-by-single-or-double

Comment: Looks like you need `.match(/"[^"]*"|\S+|\s+/g)`, please check if it is in line with your requirements.

Comment: Your comment works.  Thank you.  I will say so in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want to tokenize a string into whitespace and non-whitespace char chunks, but also separate `"..."` like substrings between quotes into separate elements.

You may achieve it using

```
s.match(/"[^"]*"|\S+|\s+/g)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OdDhJy/1).

**Details**

- `"[^"]*"` - a `"`, then any 0+ chars other than a quote, and then a `"` (**NOTE**: to match regular escape sequences, you need to replace it with `"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^"\\]*)*"`)
- `|` - or
- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `|` - or
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespace chars.

JS demo:

```js
var s = "[4,4]  \"This is fun\"\n2  2 +\n#";
console.log(s.match(/"[^"]*"|\S+|\s+/g));
```