# explode string conditionally in php

Tags: php, string, explode

I have a string with spaces as follows.

```
$name = 'name="shadow" msg="Your message"';
```

I want to explode the string such as to get `name="shadow"` and `msg="Your message"`. But the message inside msg is also splitted

On exploding using `whitespace` i am not getting desired output

```
$code = explode(' ', $name);
```

I want to get

```
$code[0] = 'name="shadow"'
$code[1] = 'msg="Your message"'
```

But i get this

```
$code[0] = 'name="shadow"'
$code[1] = 'msg="Your'
$code[3] = 'message"'
```

Comment: What is your expected answer and code which you tried?

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex for splitting a string using space when not surrounded by single or double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366202/regex-for-splitting-a-string-using-space-when-not-surrounded-by-single-or-double)

Comment: Got the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `/(?<=\")\s/` regex in [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php). The regex select any space after `"` character

```
$name = 'name="shadow" msg="Your message"';
$code = preg_split('/(?<=\")\s/', $name);
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/eZt4L)