# Java split string with regex, anything inside Double Quotes

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to split a string such as `String s = "do not split this \"split this\"";`

```
String[] split = s.split("(?<=\\s)| (?=\") | ((?=[^A-Za-z0-9])|(?<=[^A-Za-z0-9]));
```

will give me `["do", " ", "not", " ", "split", "this", " ", "split this"];`

I would like to keep all words, white spaces as well, but ignore anything inside double quotes~

Comment: You can match that using `String regex="\"([^\"]*)\"|\\S+|\\s+";` and if there is Group 1 match, get the Group 1 value, else, get the whole match value.

Comment: i want to keep words and white spaces, but anything that are in between quotes, i want to keep as whole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*just a guess:*

```
String s = "do not split this \"split this\"";
String[] split = s.split( "(?<!\".{0,255}) | (?!.*\".*)" );  // do, not, split, this, "split this"
```

*don't split at the blank, if the blank is surrounded by quotes*
split at the blank when the 255 characters to the left *and* all characters to the right of the blank are no quotes