# Regex for splitting a string using space and special characters when not surrounded by single or double quotes

Tags: java, regex

Regarding this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366202/regex-for-splitting-a-string-using-space-when-not-surrounded-by-single-or-double), what about adding special characters to the mix? And also saving the spaces into the list as well.

Example

```
This is a string, that "will be" highlighted when your 'regular expression' matches something!!!
```

Gives me

```
This

is

a

string
,

that

"will be"

highlighted

when

your

'regular expression'

matches

something
!
!
!
```

But i wasn't able to make it work with special characters as well...

I tried `(?=[^A-Za-z0-9])|(?<=[^A-Za-z0-9])|[\\s\"']+|\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'`,
which results in

This

is

a

string
,

that

"
will

be
"

highlighted

when

your

'
regular

expression
'

matches

```
something
!
!
!
```

EDIT
I managed to find the regex i needed myself

```
(\"[^\"]*\")|\\W|\\w+
```

This will split all words, whitespaces and special characters. It also keeps everything that are within double quotes as one element by itself

Comment: Which "special" characters did you use and why did it not work? What was the result?

Comment: i added (?=[^A-Za-z0-9])|(?<=[^A-Za-z0-9]) into the pattern, i want to do for all special characters

Comment: What does the whole pattern look like that did not work?

Comment: edited the question

Comment: Stating your question as a variant of a linked question is problematic and unnecessary, especially when the earlier question is quite short. It would be better to state a complete question, possibly mentioning that it is similar to the earlier one, giving the link. If the earlier question were deleted (perhaps not likely) your question would become a ship without an anchor. If readers have a question about the earlier question who are they to ask for clarification? Lastly, "...adding special characters to the mix?" and "...saving the spaces into the list as well." are vague.

Comment: This part of the pattern `[\\s\"']+` is missing the leading `^` and should be `[^\\s\"']+` The two parts that you added to the alternation are lookaround assertions and are non consuming. See https://regex101.com/r/Pbi2Hn/1 where the matches are. It is still not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: can you provide an example of input and expected output