# Groovy string split regular expression is not working properly

Tags: groovy

I'm using Groovy `split()` method and I have the following code

```
def value = '-t "not @healthcheck"'

println(value.split(/[^\s"']+|"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)'/))
```

I grabbed the regular expression from [Regex for splitting a string using space when not surrounded by single or double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366202/regex-for-splitting-a-string-using-space-when-not-surrounded-by-single-or-double)

Basically I want to split my string by whitespace but not if it's surrounded by single/double quotes.

My end result I want is `[-t, not @healthcheck]` but I'm getting `[,  ,  ]`. I don't understand why all the values are empty. Maybe my regular expression isn't correct or I don't understand groovy syntax messing up something.

Comment: Can you guarantee that there wont be quoted `"` (e.g. `\"`) inside the
quoted string?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use `split()` here.
I'd rather use pattern matching like so:

```
def value = '-t "not @healthcheck"    -t "111" -v "222" -c ahska@jhd'

def list = ( value =~ /(-[a-z]+)\s+"?([^"-]+)"?/ ).collect{ _, key, val -> [ key, val ] }

println list.join( '\n' )
```

prints:

```
[-t, not @healthcheck]
[-t, 111]
[-v, 222]
[-c, ahska@jhd]
```