# Regular expression to split by whitespaces that are not inside double/single quotes?

Tags: regex, groovy

If I have a string:
`String string = "Hi my name is "Bob Peters""`

I want to split the string by whitespaces only if it's not surrounded by quotes. But also, I don't want to include the quotes in my final result.

So the end result would be

`Hi, my, name, is, Bob Peters`

Where the name is together and the rest are split up.

In groovy, here is what I have so far:

```
def text = "Hi my name is 'Bob Peters'"
def newText = text.split(/\s(?=(?:[^'"`]*(['"`])[^'"`]*\1)*[^'"`]*$)/);
println(newText)
```

this results in

```
Hi
my
name
is
`Bob Peters`
```

But I need to be able to remove the single/double quotes surrounding `Bob Peters` too

Comment: How is this different to [Groovy string split regular expression is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66308474/groovy-string-split-regular-expression-is-not-working-properly)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest options is to have an additional step to remove the quotes, as below

```
​def text = "'Hi there' my name is 'Bob Peters' 'Additional quotes'"
def newText = text.split(/\s(?=(?:[^'"`]*(['"`])[^'"`]*\1)*[^'"`]*$)/);
print(newText.collect {
    it.replaceAll(/^['"`](.*)['"`]$/,'$1');
})
```

It would print `[Hi there, my, name, is, Bob Peters, Additional quotes]`

---

Alternatively, we can consider a `space` optionally preceded and followed by quotes `` ['"`] `` as split pattern.

But this will not remove `quotes` at the start and end of the string. We need to include alternate split pattern to include quotes at the start and end of string.

So the pattern becomes

```
^['"`]|['"`]$|['"`]?<<< Your Existing Pattern >>>['"`]?.
```

There is one another issue with this approach. If quotes appear at the start of the string like `'Hi there` ...```, then an empty string will be prepended in the output.

So we will include a `space` at the beginning of the string and always ignore the first element in the result array. The final patter will be

```
^\s['"`]|['"`]$|['"`]?<<<Your Existing Pattern>>>['"`]?
```

**Groovy Code:**

```
def text = "Hi there my name is 'Bob Peters' 'Additional quotes'"
def newText = (" " + text).split(/^\s['"`]|['"`]$|['"`]?\s(?=(?:[^'"`]*(['"`])[^'"`]*\1)*[^'"`]*$)['"`]?/);
print(newText[1..newText.size()-1])​
```

Will print `[Hi, there, my, name, is, Bob Peters, Additional quotes]`

---

*Note:* The positive lookahead, `` \s(?=(?:[^'"`]*(['"`])[^'"`]*\1)*[^'"`]*$) `` will not handle `nested quotes`. Example

```
Hi there `Outer quotes 'inner quotes'`
```

will not be split.