# Regex for splitting words separated by spaces, but preserve phrases inside single or double quotes (python)

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing, split

I am new to regex and the re module in python. I need to find a way to parse a string such as:

`Hello world "Boston Red Sox", 'Pepperoni Pizza', 'Cheese Pizza's', beer`

into a list such as:

```
['Hello', 'world', 'Boston Red Sox', 'Pepperoni Pizza', 'Cheese Pizza's', 'beer']
```

I need to omit the outer quotes from the final list, but preserve ' and " inside the phrases if they exist. I.e. `"Cheese Pizza's"` = `Cheese Pizza's`

I am aware of this post: [Regex for splitting a string using space when not surrounded by single or double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366202/regex-for-splitting-a-string-using-space-when-not-surrounded-by-single-or-double) however I am having trouble translating the regex into a pattern that python re can understand.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```py
import re
string = '''Hello world "Boston Red Sox", 'Pepperoni Pizza', 'Cheese Pizza's', beer'''
string = re.sub(r"(^|,\s*)'|'(?=\s*,)", r'\1"', string)
print([f"{x}{y}{z}" for x,y,z in re.findall(r"""'([^']*)'|"([^"]*)"|([^\s,]+)""", string)])
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##RYxNSwNBDIbv/RUhl8zqIIjnIujFY6nH7hZaNmsHxpkhM8X9/O1riqKnPHnf5ElDucTwtK7uM0UpILzJRVz4gC0Q0Rt7H@Erim8BX2IuMcCeW3iPPVqgHafEEoODnRvHE2n0emHO/LtnTc7MoqZ/rfBDvp6NoDnOts53Fc1knrdKtlKpUP2I@vdzX22SjmIOHU79Mg3LNC4IXRTo7WBHcOHm61xoT96rE5HM4UjNzYpKqISzQp1tc19p/2duqnX9Bg).

**Results**: `['Hello', 'world', 'Boston Red Sox', 'Pepperoni Pizza', "Cheese Pizza's", 'beer']`

**EXPLANATION (REGEX #1)**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ,                        ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  '                        '\''
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  '                        '\''
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ,                        ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

**EXPLANATION (REGEX #2)**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  '                        '\''
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^']*                    any character except: ''' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  '                        '\''
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\s,]+                  any character except: whitespace (\n,
                             \r, \t, \f, and " "), ',' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
```