# How to ignore space in quote with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible that my change function ignore words in " "?
By ignore I mean that it doesn't remove spaces in " "

Currently function outputs:

Input:

```
te s s sdg gdg sdg "gh hh"
```

Output:

```
te,s,s,sdg,gdg,sdg,"gh,hh"
```

I want:

```
te,s,s,sdg,gdg,sdg,gh hh
```

Code:

```js
function change() {
    var data = $("#data").val();

    var dataArr= [];
    var reg1 = /\s+/g;
    var reg2 = /;+/g;
    var reg3 = /•+/g;
    var reg4 = /^-+\s*/;
    var regex= [reg1,reg2,reg3,reg4];
    
    regex.forEach(function(i) {
        data= data.replace(i, ",");
        dataArr= data.split(",");
    });
    
    $("#data").val(data);
    
}
```

Comment: With a regex, yes. However, if you also want escape characters for the `"`s, it'll be more complex.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex for splitting a string using space when not surrounded by single or double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366202/regex-for-splitting-a-string-using-space-when-not-surrounded-by-single-or-double)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a pattern with a capture group, and based on the groups, replace the `,` with a space or return the capture inside the double quotes.

```
"([^"]+)"|\s+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/m7R6So/1)

```js
const s = `te s s sdg gdg sdg "gh hh"`;
console.log(s.replace(/"([^"]+)"|\s+/g, (m, g1) => g1 ? g1 : ","));
```

If you don't only want to replace `-` only at the start of the string, you can list all the characters in a character class that you want to replace with a comma.

```
"([^"]+)"|[\s;•-]+
```

- `"([^"]+)"` Match `"`, capture 1+ times any char between the double quotes in **group 1** and match `"` again
- `|` Or
- `[\s;•-]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed characters in the character class

```js
const s = `te s s ;;- s•dg gdg sdg "gh hh"`;
console.log(s.replace(/"([^"]+)"|[\s;•-]+/g, (m, g1) => g1 ? g1 : ","));
```

Comment: You are absolutly right I meant I don't want to split spaces in quote "  sd sd s"

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
function change() {
    var data = $("#data").val();

    var dataArr = [];
    var reg1 = /"([^"]*)"|\s+/g;
    var reg2 = /;+/g;
    var reg3 = /•+/g;
    var reg4 = /^-+\s*/;
    var regex= [reg1,reg2,reg3,reg4];

    regex.forEach(function(i) {
        data= data.replace(i, (_,x) => x || ",");
    dataArr= data.split(",");
    });
    $("#data").val(data);
}
```

The `var reg1 = /"([^"]*)"|\s+/g;` will match strings between double quotes and capture the part between `"` into Group 1, or will match one or more whitespaces.

The `data= data.replace(i, (_,x) => x || ",");` part will now either replace the match with `,` if Group 1 did not participate in the match, or with Group 1 contents.