# How can I gather tokens in C#, seperated by spaces, but ignore spaces when surrounded by quotes?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am making a personal terminal, it doesn't do a lot and doesn't really have a specific purpose, I'm mostly just bored. I have been banging my head against a wall for about a day now trying to do this manually before trying to research it.

When I did research it I found this and changed it a bit to apply to my code

```
var re = new Regex("(?<=\")[^\"]*(?=\")|[^\" ]+");
string[] NewTokens = re.Matches(fullstring).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
```

The `fullstring` variable is all of my tokens clumped together (basically just the user input for a command), not seperated by spacing. Just the normal string before it is deconstructed into a `string[]` of tokens.

I need this string to be seperated by spaces but ignore that when there are quotes. For example if I wanted to make a command that prints out a message into the console I would do:
`print "Hello World!"` as my command.
The output I would like is:

[0] -> print
[1] -> Hello World!

The code example seems to work...but when I try to run a command that doesnt have quotes like: 
(print being the command the help command looks for)
`help print`

The output is:
[0] -> helpprint

The tokens *should* be:
[0] -> help
[1] -> print

Please help. Normally I wouldn't ask for help, but I really can't find a fix for this online or by myself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex for splitting a string using space when not surrounded by single or double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366202/regex-for-splitting-a-string-using-space-when-not-surrounded-by-single-or-double)

Comment: `Regex.Matches(input, @"[^\s""]+|""([^""]*)""").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Groups[1].Value : m.Value);` should do the trick.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine I have already seen that and unfortunately that solution is for java not C#.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine That second solution code doesnt really work as it returns a IEnumerable<string>. I need it to be a string[] for processing.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine I slapped a .ToArray() at the end of `Regex.Matches(input, @"[^\s""]+|""([^""]*)""").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Groups[1].Value : m.Value)` and it spit out a string[] but it doesnt seem to act differently from my previous method.

Comment: I checked both your samples (`print "Hello World!"` and `help print`) with the pattern `(?<=\")[^\"]*(?=\")|[^\" ]+` and everything looks fine.

Answer (score -1):

Just change the Select this way to return the matched group

```
string[] NewTokens = re.Matches(fullstring).Select(m => m.Groups[0].Value).ToArray();
```

Comment: This results in an error where "Matches(fullstring) does not contain .Select". Not the exact error message. visual studio wouldnt let me copy-paste.

Comment: Maybe you are missing Linq, you can add `using System.Linq;` and it should let you use the `Select` function